# Possible to have pdf file download as attachment if pop ups are blocked in browser for Angular project?

Tags: angular, pdf, popup, blob, attachment

I have the following code that runs when a pdf blob file is returned from the server for a report:

```
this.http.print_report()
  .subscribe( (pdf) => {
      this.file = pdf;
    },
    () => {
    },
    () => {
      this.pdf = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.file)], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(this.pdf);
      // Open window
      window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    });
```

If I wanted to do a clean way of having the file download as an attachment if they have pop ups blocked in their browser settings, how would I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) or if handing large files, use [StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js).

Also, read [this intro](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/wiki/Saving-a-remote-file#using-http-header) first to explore other options and see if you actually need `FileSaver` or a simple `Content-Disposition`

Sample Use:

```
import * as FileSaver from "file-saver";

this.itemService
        .downloadAttachment(itemNumber, attachmentId)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            FileSaver.saveAs(data.content, data.fileName);
          },
          error => {
            console.error("Download Error", error);
          }
        );
```